# Create NuGet package which installs references with Copy Local set to false

Tags: nuget

Is there a way to create a NuGet package where when the package is installed into a project it adds references to the dlls with "Copy Local" set to false?

I assume it would be some kind of script within the 'install.ps1' file.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why you don't want to get the files copied locally?

Comment: @kiewic that is an excellent question. A question I wish my 5-years ago self had docukented because I have no idea at this point!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can do this with install.ps1, as you guessed.

Here's an example install.ps1 that will flip the flag on System.dll every time you run it.  You should be able to get an idea how to do what you want using this example:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

foreach ($reference in $project.Object.References)
{
    if($reference.Name -eq "System")
    {
        if($reference.CopyLocal -eq $true)
        {
            $reference.CopyLocal = $false;
        }
        else
        {
            $reference.CopyLocal = $true;
        }
    }
}
```

But this MSDN documentation should help.

- The `Object` Hanselman uses resolves to the [VSProject Interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171024)
- The `$project` variable NuGet gives you resolves to the [Project Interface.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x29xdte5)

Comment: I found a Hanselman post about 'adding' references in a NuGet Powershell script: $project.Object.References.Add("Microsoft.CSharp");.  That gets me closer but I am having trouble locating documentation showing how to choose and modify a reference for changing 'copy local'

Comment: Updated the answer with a better example.

Comment: When I do this in VS2015 I often end up with duplicates
<Reference Include="..">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>

Answer (score 7):

I think this install.ps1 does what you ask for - all DLLs added by the package are given a Copy Local value of false. Note that here I'm not doing anything with the AssemblyReferences list other than getting all of the names from it - you may have to do something more if you want conditions based on target framework, etc.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$asms = $package.AssemblyReferences | %{$_.Name}

foreach ($reference in $project.Object.References)
{
    if ($asms -contains $reference.Name + ".dll")
    {
        $reference.CopyLocal = $false;
    }
}
```